# Alamofire Swift 2.0 json response

Tags: swift, swift2, alamofire

I keep getting this error:

```
 '(_, _, _, _) -> Void' is not convertible to 'Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void'
```

I looked in a lot of places, and tried the changes but it gives me errors else where.

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://example.com/test.php", parameters: ["username": usernamep]).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
        if (json != nil) {
            var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
            if let data = jsonObj["flist"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                datasMentions = data
             ....
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well you shouldn't have `(_, _, _, _ )`, they should be `(respond, json, error, _)` these are the responses.

Answer (score 0):

With a couple of trials, I got it.

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET,"http://example.com/test.php", parameters: ["username": usernamep])
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let json = response.result.value {
        var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
        if let data = jsonObj["flist"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
            datasMentions = data
         ....
        }
            }
    }
```